# Leaflet DomEvent.addListener - why doesn't 'click' work, but 'dblclick','mouseout','mouseover' do?

Tags: leaflet, plugins

I tried to edit this [Leaflet Geocoder Plugin](https://github.com/k4r573n/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder) in order to add an `"X" close button` to collapse the expanded `geocoder div`.

The plugin normally works like this: [demo](http://k4r573n.github.io/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder/).

I have fiddled around with it, and now it looks like this: [**jsFiddle** (line 56-57)](http://jsfiddle.net/ralu_bur/mtvym498/1/)

My edits include creating a submit button..

```
var xclose = document.createElement('input');
xclose.type = "submit";
xclose.value = 'X';
form.appendChild(xclose);
```

..and changing the listeners from:

```
L.DomEvent.addListener(container, 'mouseover', this._expand, this);
L.DomEvent.addListener(container, 'mouseout', this._collapse, this);
```

to:

```
L.DomEvent.addListener(container, 'click', this._expand, this);
L.DomEvent.addListener(xclose, 'click', this._collapse, this); //doesn't work
```

**Question:**

Why doesn't `L.DomEvent.addListener(xclose, 'click', this._collapse, this);` work, but the other click events do?

```
L.DomEvent.addListener(xclose, 'dblclick', this._collapse, this); //works
L.DomEvent.addListener(xclose, 'mouseout', this._collapse, this); //works
L.DomEvent.addListener(xclose, 'mouseover', this._collapse, this); //works
```

Could it be because of `L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);`? If so, how can I make it work? I tried removing that line, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding 
 `L.DomEvent.addListener(xclose, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop);` 

before the other listeners have the desired effect. The geocoder extension has a default behavior for click event and the above command stops the default click behavior.See [jsFiddle line 56](http://jsfiddle.net/nettaB/mtvym498/5/)